# How to build modules into one uber jar using the maven-jar plugin

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar

I'm currently working on migrating an ANT project to a Maven Multimodule project which is to be used in an automated build and deploy instance. The ultimate goal is to produce the same output file from the automated build tool running from a POM.xml instead of a build.xml file, where the internal folder structure is completely the same instead of modified to a Maven archetypal structure.
So far, I have modulated the project and the structure looks something like this:

```
-- module 1 (EAR)
--- submodule1 (jar)
--- submodule2 (jar)
--- submodule3 (jar)
--- submodule4 (jar)
--- submodule5 (jar)
--- submodule6 (war)
--- submodule7 (war)
--- lib
--- sharedLib

-- module 2 (EAR)
--- submodule 1 (war)
--- submodule 2 (war)
--- submodule 3 (jar)
--- lib

-- module 3 (EAR)
--- submodule 1 (war)
--- submodule 2 (jar)
--- lib
```

However, what I need to do is produce an uber jar containing the submodules, an application.py file and a single jar file. So far, when I apply the maven-jar-plugin in the super parent POM, it causes the sub parents to package to jar making the individual ear modules individual jar files. Is there a way that I make the jar plugin package the ear modules in one collective jar file at the package?

Comment: I am currently trying to do something like this, did you found a solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068692/how-to-create-jar-from-submodules-of-module?noredirect=1#comment50163428_31068692